# Word or phrase for an argument that shows a claim is false?

Tags: single-word-requests, logic

What is a word or phrase for argument that shows the presupposition is false?

**E.g.**:

> Someone said writing requires big hands. I showed them that someone can write well with small hands. Therefore, I have argued against what he said.

What is this method of argument known as?

Comment: A counter-argument?

Comment: Those voting to close, please show how the "research" may be done.

Answer (score 5):

That's a **counterexample**.

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counterexample):

> An example that opposes or contradicts an idea or theory.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterexample) has it stronger than that:

> an example that refutes or disproves a proposition or theory.

(I personally would have written it as **counter-example**, but all the dictionaries I looked at excluded the hyphen, so it looks like the non-hyphenated version is preferred.)

Comment: Why do you not use the OED? It is vastly more extensive than Merriam Webster. If you are a UK Council Tax payer you will very likely have free on-line access to the OED (If your local authority library has a subscription).

Comment: @WS2 Thanks for the tip - I do actually have an old printed one, but I'm sure the online version will be more up-to-date. I will look into it. Here though, I'm trying to provide links another reader can click through to without any subscription... which is a good idea, surely? In this specific case I looked at a few alternatives to check whether they differed substantively, and (to my surprise) they did, so I posted two sample definitions to illustrate the range of opinion.

Comment: If you have a 'printed' OED it runs to about 30 volumes! I think what you may mean is the Shorter Oxford Dictionary, which is two volumes. But the online OED is vastly more than a English dictionary. It is a dictionary of the *history of English*. It is a major source of etymology, and provides examples of the use of every single word from earliest times. The Americans who use the site do not have access unless they buy a subscription. Are you a member of your local library. If so look at your library card.

Comment: @WS2: It isn't possible to link to the subscription OED, so less than helpful in this situation though it's certainly a good resource for private research.

Comment: @WS2 there's also the compact edition of the OED, which is not "shorter"; the print is just very small (four pages of the original on each page).  Also, I, an American, have access through my local library.

Comment: I think that you may have a typo and that instead of 'Miriam-Webster' you wanted to write 'Merriam-Webster'

Comment: @SamuelVimes Heh. Embarrassing. Thanks, I've corrected it now.

Comment: @TimLymington Why do you say it is not possible to link to the subscription OED? I am in constant linkage with it through my local library card.

Comment: @WS2: Those who are unfortunate enough not to belong to a local library and not rich enough to afford a subscription (which means most users of this site) cannot use your links.

Comment: @TimLymington But if you live in Britain it costs you nothing to join a local library. Or does it? Who do you pay your council tax to?

Comment: @WS2: Many ELU users do not enjoy the felicity of living in Britain. Many of those who do have not joined a local library, for whatever reason (or have done so, but have not logged on to oed.com)  I do not think you will succeed in changing either of these facts, and until you do, links to the OED are not helpful. I meant no more than that.

Comment: @TimLymington But people who are enthusiastic users such as your good self, I would have thought, would benefit immeasurably from getting a library card and a free connection to the OED.

Answer (score 4):

rebuttal, *n*

[rebut](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rebut) verb (rebuts, rebutting, rebutted)
[with object]

> 1 Claim or prove that (evidence or an accusation) is false:
>   *he had to rebut charges of acting for the convenience of his political friends*

syn: *refutation, denial, countering, invalidation, negation, contradiction*
"now that you've heard the accusations, have you a rebuttal?" (source: Google Search)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the term you are looking for is ***disprove by contradiction***. However, I think that Morton's ***counterexample*** is also a very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convey the idea that your colleague was attempting to falsely convey the notion of truth in his argument you could say:

> A colleague argued **speciously** that writing requires big hands. I rebutted
>   with my own evidence which exposed his artifice.